# Categories/Sub-categories Help

Tags: category, magento-community

Apologies if this has been created in the wrong section.

I am interested in getting started with Magento and wanted to find out about the following for a website selling electronics accessories.

In particular to display the products to purchase once the customer has selected/reached a certain level of category/sub-category. For example, if a customer was looking for a battery for a Canon EOS 650D digital camera:

Customer would first choose the device type, Digital Camera. Then the manufacturer, Canon. Then Digital SLR etc...

Digital Camera > Canon > Digital SLR > EOS > 650D

So at each point only the category values are displayed for the customer to make further selection. Once they reach the desired model in this case 650D, the accessories or actual products to purchase are displayed.

This has to be achieve dynamically as opposed to loads of static pages.

Also, can all this information be uploaded by way of a product feed?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light as to whether this is possible in Magento. If possible and not breaking forum rules, are there any sites running Magento that have achieved this that I can take a look at?

Many Thanks in advance to help out this potential newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could use layered navigation. You would create attributes in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes.

So you may have an attribute for Brand, one for Model, Product Type etc.

Then on the attribute properties page, you can select 'Use in Layered Navigation'.

This would give your user the option to filter product collections on any page by a combination of attributes. E.g. Brand and Model, Product Type and Brand etc.

There may be other ways, but that could be a good start.